# How to update an environment variable based on another environment variable in Ember JS?

Tags: ember.js

I have a use-case wherein in environment.js, we have an environment variable - isMobile which by default is set to false and channelCode is set to WEB.

```
let ENV = {
  isMobile: false,
  channelCode: "WEB"
}
```

As we cannot access the navigator object in environment.js, we set the ENV.isMobile and ENV.channelCode in index.js accordingly. We check if the request is from mobile using navigator.userAgent, then we set ENV.isMobile to true and ENV.channelCode to MOB.

```
// mobile detection check
if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
// mobile!
     ENV.isMobile = true;
     ENV.channelCode = "MOB";
} else {
     ENV.isMobile = false;
}
```

Now we have a condition wherein we need to set an environment variable based on the channelCode environment variable.

```
ENV.tenantConfig = {
    SG: {
      'accounts': `${ENV.channelCode}-SG-ABC`
    }
  }
```

Now, if the request is from Mobile, the ENV.isMobile will be set to true and ENV.channelCode will be set to MOB in index.js, will the ENV["tenantConfig"]["SG"]["accounts"] be WEB-SG-ABC or MOB-SG-ABC.

Will the changes in index.js reflect in environment.js tenantConfig variable?
If it will not be updated to MOB-SG-ABC, can you please suggest on the approach.

Answer (score 1):

the `environment.js` is a node-time setup file, so it doesn't have access to browser contexts.

Likewise, the rest of your app runs in the browser, so it does not have access to node-time information.

*However*, you can import the *compiled output* of environment.js, via:

```
import ENVConfig from '<app-name>/config/environment';
```

and if you need to adjust things based on browser information, I'd make a service:

```
ember g service runtime-env
```

```
// app/services/runtime-env.js

import Service from '@ember/service';
import ENVConfig from '<app-name>/config/environment';

export default class RuntimeEnv extends Service {
  get isMobile() {
    return /Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  } 

  get channelCode() {
    if (this.isMobile) return "MOB";
    return;
  }

  get tenantAccounts() {
    return `${this.channelCode}-SG-ABC`;
  }
}
```